# retrieve a collection type element of a dictionnary in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dictionnary in vba where each key is a string, and each value associate is a collection, this is my code :

```
Dim dict As Dictionary
Set dict = New Dictionary

Set collec=New collection

Dim i As Integer
For i=1 To 5
    collec.Add "element" & i
Next i

dict.Add "mykey",collect
```

This is where I am blocked, I would like to exploit the collection thanks to the key like this :

```
Dim test As New collection
test=dict("mykey")
```

But this is not working

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `Set` keyword when assigning an object.  You also have some typos in your code (`collec` vs `collect`).  You should use `Option Explicit` to catch these types of errors:

```
Option Explicit

Dim dict As Dictionary
Set dict = New Dictionary

Set collec = New collection

Dim i As Integer
For i=1 To 5
    collec.Add "element" & i
Next i

dict.Add "mykey", collec  'fix typo

Dim test As Collection
Set test = dict("mykey")   'use Set to assign object
```

Comment: The "collec" syntaxe mistake was a bad copy paste on my post, it's not from where the error is coming.

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub M_snb()
 With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
  For j = 1 To 5
   Set .Item("c_" & .Count) = New Collection
  Next

  .Item("c_2").Add "first"
  .Item("c_2").Add "second"
  .Item("c_2").Add "third"

  MsgBox .Item("c_2").Item(2)
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Mind to explain this a bit?

Comment: 1. Add five items ('c_1', 'c_2','c_3','c_4','c_5') to the Dictionary. Each item consists of an empty collection. 2. In this example: add 3 items to the empty collection in item 'c_2' of the dictionary. 3. You can read the second item in the collection in dictionary-item 'c_2' using..item("c_2").item(2)